# syschronized getter and setters but need to avoid deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have synchronized static getter and setter like:

```
public synchronized static int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public synchronized static void setValue(int Val) {
    value = Val;
}
```

If I need to increment value, I will use something like

```
setValue(getValue() + 1);
```

There might be a thread that sets the 'value' and immediately tries to get the 'value'. In such a case can a deadlock occur? If yes, then how to avoid it?

Comment: Add syncronized incrementValue() method.

Comment: And what about volatile variable in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There might be a thread that sets the 'value' and immediately tries to get the 'value'. In such a case can a deadlock occur? If yes, then how to avoid it?

It's not going to be deadlock unless two locks are involved (see [deadlock definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)).  However you *are* going to have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_conditions#Software) when the get is called and then the setter is called.  For example, two threads could call the `getValue()` value method, one after the other and then go back to call the `setValue(...)` one after another.  The second setter would then overwrite the increment of the other.

1. thread-a calls `getValue()` which equals 1
2. thread-b calls `getValue()` which equals 1
3. thread-a increments the value
4. thread-a calls `setValue(...)` with the incremented value of 2
5. thread-b increments the value
6. thread-b calls `setValue(...)` with the incremented value of 2

So the answer should be 3 but because of race conditions, it is going to be 2.

Continuing with your code, you need to have a `synchronized static void increment()` method which does *both* the get, increment, and set.  You need to be `synchronized` because `++` is not an atomic operation.

```
public synchronized static int increment() {
    value++;
}
```

All this said, you should consider using an `AtomicInteger` instead which takes care of the race conditions around increment and memory synchronization for you.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` uses the same object as a lock (the class itself). so a deadlock will never happen in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> There might be a thread that sets the 'value' and immediately tries to get the 'value'. In such a case can a deadlock occur?

No.  For a couple of reasons.

1. A thread cannot deadlock while trying to acquire a primitive lock that it already holds.  Primitive locks are reentrant.  Attempting to acquire a lock that you are already holding does not block.  Rather, it just increments a count in the lock ... which will be decremented by the corresponding lock release action.
2. In this case, you are not even going to reenter the lock.  When the statement is executed, you first call `getValue()` which acquires and releases the lock.  Then you call `setValue(int)` which acquires and releases the lock again.  As you can see, the execution does not attempt to acquire a lock while holding the same lock.
3. In fact, deadlock (with primitive locks) requires *at least* two different threads and two different locks.

---

Finally, as @Gray points out, `setValue(getValue() + 1)` does not increment the value reliably ... unless you perform that sequence while holding the lock.  There is a time window between the `getValue()` and `setValue()` calls in which another thread could change the value.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, synchronized method is not necessary, just mark the `value` variable as `volatile`

```
volatile private Object var;
```

but for read-modify updates you have to synchronize the object, but beware about the synchronized method, because it accepts a not null Object reference(primitives are not allowed)
so the code would be like this

```
volatile static private int value;
public int getValue(){return value;}
public void setValue_direct(int id){value=val;}
public synchronized void setValue_increment(){value++;}
```

[this link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#vol0) would help you about volatile keyword

Comment: I really don't see any problem here buddy, the method for incrementing is synchronized, the situation you mentioned is not possible while increment method is synchronized and variable is volatile, would you please provide some link which I'm wrong?! thanks.

Comment: The issue is that although the `value` is volatile, there is still a race condition between the `setValue_direct(...)` updating of `value` and the `setValue_increment(...)`.  The increment does 3 operations, right?  get/increment/set.  If the get happens and then the value is set with `setValue_direct(...)` then the increment will overwrite the set.  So the value could be 5, the setter might set it to 100, and then the increment would store it as 6, overwriting the 100.

Comment: so this is not a issue/problem! and your solution doesn't solve the mentioned issue anyway, because thread get the value, then thread two set the value with increment then thread b change it to new value. the difference is just about the return type! your method returns int, mine is void, so I am still thinking there is no problem!

Comment: Sigh.  Now sure how to explain it any better.  My solution _does_ solve it by adding a `synchronized` increment value but _not_ removing the `synchronized` keyword from the set method.  It also recommends using the `AtomicInteger` which fixes this with `volatile` by using a `compareAndSet(...)` loop.

Comment: 1. increment is called by one thread.  It gets `value`. 2. At the same time `setvalue` is called in another thread which sets `value`. 3. the first thread now does the ++ and then stores to `value`.  The result that is stored overwrites the `setvalue` change.  Do you understand that ++ is 3, non-atomic operations?

Comment: for direct-modify updates setting the variable as volatile is enough, and there is no need for synchronization, by using `AtomicInteger` the problem is still exist, no matter what kind of object is begin used even with your solution using `AtomicInteger` or x or y or z.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39776/discussion-between-gray-and-user2511414)

Comment: 'beware about the synchronized method, because it accepts a not null Object reference(primitives are not allowed)' . Does this mean that for int value, i don't need synchronized methods? how come?

Comment: @user2441441 you cannot synchronize primitive or null values, becasue synchronizing works with heap, no object reference(pointer) [this link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#syncblock) would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment value, declare separate synchronized method. Or use AtomicInteger instead of int variable (then no need for getter/setter/incrementor to be synchronized).